# Can GroupBy and concat not be used together?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do some sorting based on the count() within a bundle, but I am not having much luck.

I have this sorting that works fine by sorting all the null values last

```
customerBasket.ItemsInBasket = customerBasket.ItemsInBasket.Where(s => s.BundleId != null)
                                                                       .OrderBy(s => s.BundleId)
                                                                       .ThenBy(s => s.ThisItemsCountWithinBundle)
                                                                       .Concat(customerBasket.ItemsInBasket.Where(s => s.BundleId == null))
                                                                       .ToList();
```

But then when I want to use concat again to sort "non full" bundles and put them last this cannot be done, I am trying this

```
 customerBasket.ItemsInBasket = customerBasket.ItemsInBasket.GroupBy(s => s.BundleId)
                                                                       .Where(s => s.Count() == 3)
                                                                       .Concat(customerBasket.ItemsInBasket.GroupBy(s => s.BundleId)
                                                                       .Where(s => s.Count() < 3)
                                                                       .SelectMany(s => s.ToList()));
```

But this gives me the following error message

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1929  'IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ItemInBasket>>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Concat(IQueryable, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'   slapi   C:\Users\Matt\source\repos\SLAPI\Utils\BasketHelpers.cs 20  Active

Not sure how I can fix this problem.

Comment: A group create a two dimensional array [key, list<object>] so there is no method to concat two groups [key,list<object>].Concat([key,list<object>]).

Comment: Ok so my only chance is to introduce another property and use that ?

Comment: What type of results do you expect?  Is it List<ItemInBasket>, then you need to use SelectMany on both items you are concat before you concat.

Comment: @jdweng yes a List<ItemInBasket> Not sure I understand what you mean though

Comment: You have two GroubBy's.  SelectMany flattens the two dimensional arrays to a single array.  So you want SelectMany([key,List<object>]).Concat(SelectMany([key,List<object>]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a misplaced parentheses causing you problems.  Let's split the problematic one up to an equivalent version with a few temporary variables:

```
var full = customerBasket.ItemsInBasket.GroupBy(s => s.BundleId)
                                       .Where(s => s.Count() == 3);
var nonFull = customerBasket.ItemsInBasket.GroupBy(s => s.BundleId)
                                          .Where(s => s.Count() < 3)
                                          .SelectMany(s => s.ToList());
customerBasket.ItemsInBasket = full.Concat(nonFull);
```

This is what you typed, and is giving the error.  Hopefully, this shows where the problem is coming from (SelectMany is changing the type of nonFull, so it is not something you can Concat with full).  You need to move the SelectMany from nonFull to after the Concat.

In the version without the temporaries, this should be as simple as moving a closing parentheses.